# C++: Everytime I read in by fstream I got 1 extra character at the end

Tags: c++, fstream

Everytime I read in by fstream I got 1 extra character at the end, How can I avoid this?

EDIT:

```
ifstream readfile(inputFile);
ofstream writefile(outputFile);
char c;
while(!readfile.eof()){
      readfile >> c;
      //c = shiftChar(c, RIGHT, shift);
      writefile << c;
}
readfile.close();
writefile.close();
```

Comment: Post the code that causes the problem. I woulkd guess that you have opened the file in text (rather than binary)  mode and are trying to read it with read(), but who knows.

Comment: Actual code would help.  Could this be the newline character('\n')?

Comment: sorry guys, just update my post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This typically results from testing for the end of file incorrectly. You normally want to do something like:

```
while (infile>>variable) ...
```

or:

```
while (std::getline(infile, whatever)) ...
```

but NOT:

```
while (infile.good()) ...
```

or:

```
while (!infile.eof()) ...
```

The first two do a read, check whether it failed, and if so exit the loop. The latter two attempt a read, process what's now in the variable, and then exit the loop on the *next* iteration if the previous attempt failed. On the last iteration, what's in the variable after the failed read will normally be whatever was in it previously, so loops like either of the second two will typically appear to process the last item in the file twice.

To copy one file to another easily, consider using something like this:

```
// open the files:
ifstream readfile(inputFile);
ofstream writefile(outputFile);

// do the copy:
writefile << readfile.rdbuf();
```

This works well for small files, but can slow down substantially for a larger file. In such a case, you typically want to use a loop, `read`ing from one file and `write`ing to the other. This also has possibilities for subtle errors as well. One way that's been tested and generally work reasonably well looks like this:

```cpp
    std::ifstream input(in_filename, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream output(out_filename, std::ios::binary);

    const size_t buffer_size = 512 * 1024;
    char buffer[buffer_size];

    std::size_t read_size;
    while (input.read(buffer, buffer_size), (read_size = input.gcount()) > 0)
        output.write(buffer, input.gcount());
```

Comment: awesome !! that solve the problem. U might elaborate on why `.eof()` is not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, it appears what you're trying to do is copy the contents of one file to another?

If so, I'd try something like this:

```
ifstream fin(inputFile, ios::binary);

fin.seekg(0, ios::end);
long fileSize = fin.tellg();
fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);

char *pBuff = new char[fileSize];
fin.read(pBuff, fileSize);
fin.close();

ofstream fout(outputFile, ios::binary)
fout.write(pBuff, fileSize);
fout.close;
delete [] pBuff;
```